# How is browser UI painting interleaved with servicing the JavaScript job queue?

Tags: javascript, browser

JavaScript maintains an internal Job Queue of procedures to run with a run-to-completion semantic.

How is UI painting interleaved with servicing this queue? Clearly UI painting is blocked by the running of said procedures.

Does the browser maintain a scheduler and pre-empt the emptying of the queue, or does it wait for a "breath", i.e. an empty queue before attempting a UI update?

Furthermore is the Job Queue typically a straightforward queue or is there a concept of priority (e.g. can browser jobs queue-jump)?

Comment: Please explain your downvote, so that I may improve my question.